# Using local dependencies when docker container is building

Tags: docker, go

I have a service which transitively relies on some library (which is also being developed by me). The only way to test if the library changes are correct is to run the service.

## How could I do it locally

I have two versions of that library:

- Stable version inside `vendor` folder
- Actual one with untested changes inside `GOPATH`

So I can just remove it from `vendor` and `go build` will work correctly using the version from `GOPATH`.

---

The question is what is the best way to achieve the same behavior using `docker`?
The obvious solution is just copy of local `GOPATH` into the container on build stage, but `GOPATH` size is very big and such approach is too expensive.

Comment: Are you using Go modules?  Or, is the dependent library in source control you can access at build time?  There’s `go.mod` and `go get` syntax to reference specific commits, it you can push the library to a branch.  Including the `Dockerfile` in the question would also help understanding what your current build environment is like.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I am. Actually I'm trying to do it without commit or push before testing if new changes are work. It prevents a lot of unworking commits in the source branch. So I'm looking for a way to build the service with the dependency located outside of service source code

Comment: Not fully sure I understand the problem/question. But maybe `go mod vendor` can help, no? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away

Comment: @Deancoakley, unfortunately, it won't help. I need a way to use uncommitted (located outside the service's source code) changes in the dependency library during building docker container

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to mount the library folder to container and define path in dockerfile, that way your image wont be large and the path will fetch you the dependent libraries from the mounted directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze oh sorry , i wasn't aware about that , thanks , its good to know.